# Minimize and close buttons not working in Electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, window

I'm making an app using Electron framework and I tried using buttons to close and minimize the window. I've tried multiple things for it to do this but without success.

This is what I have for the moment:
HTML:

```html
<body>
    <!-- Titlebar -->
    <button id="minimize-button">-</button>
    <button id="close-button">x</button>

    <!-- Script -->
    <script src="./js/minimize-close.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS (minimize-close.js):

```js
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

document.getElementById("minimize-button").addEventListener('click', () => {
    ipcRenderer.send('minimize-window');
});

document.getElementById("close-button").addEventListener('click', () => {
    ipcRenderer.send('close-window');
});
```

JS (index.js):

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');

function createWindow(){
    const window = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 960, height: 580,
        resizable: false, maximizable: false,
        frame: false, autoHideMenuBar: true,
        icon: './icon.ico',
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            devTools: false
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('./src/index.html');
}

// Minimize and close window
ipcMain.on('minimize-window', () => {
    window.minimize();
});

ipcMain.on('close-window', () => {
    window.close();
});

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow();

    app.on('activate', function(){
        if(BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0){
            createWindow();
        }
    });
});

app.on('window-all-closed', function(){
    if(process.platform !== 'darwin'){
        app.quit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Your remote seems incorrect, I believe it should be `const { remote } = require("electron")`, because rn you're just requiring electron, not the remote module. Also, it seems like remote is deprecated, and you should instead use ipcMain and ipcRenderer (https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main) which will let you to send events from the client to the main process.

Comment: I already tried using ipcRenderer, I'm gonna try again.

Comment: Can you add your attempt with ipcRenderer and ipcMain to your question please?

Comment: I'll do it if does not work.

Comment: Okay so, I tried and still the same results.

Comment: I think the issue may be that you don't have nodeIntegration enabled, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62437788/10213537, for enabling nodeIntegration

Comment: Even with nodeIntegration it doesn't work...

Comment: Hold on, I think you may have an issue with the scope of the `window` variable, you're defining a variable `window` to the scope of the function `createWindow` but using the variable outside of that scope. Try setting `ipcMain.on`s inside the `createWindow` function and see if that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `contextIsolation: false`.
Also I have read around that `window` must be global. If not at some point it will be collected by the garbage collector because function which created it has already finished.

```js
let window;

function createWindow(){
    window = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 960, height: 580,
        resizable: false, maximizable: false,
        frame: false, autoHideMenuBar: true,
        icon: './icon.ico',
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            // devTools: false,  // commented for debugging purposes
            contextIsolation: false
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('./src/index.html');
    window.webContents.openDevTools(); // Open dev tools to see if any error arised. In this case I saw 'require is not defined' before setting contextIsolation. Remove it when going into production.
}
```

---

**Option B: more "secure"**

If security is a concern and you want `nodeIntegration` and `contextIsolation` to retain their default secure values then `preload.js` scheme is needed.
This should be the case if remote content is loaded by your App.

**HTML**

```html
<body>
    <!-- Titlebar -->
    <button id="minimize-button">-</button>
    <button id="close-button">x</button>
</body>
```

**preload.js**

```js
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.getElementById("minimize-button").addEventListener('click', () => {
        ipcRenderer.send('minimize-window');
    });
    
    document.getElementById("close-button").addEventListener('click', () => {
        ipcRenderer.send('close-window');
    });
})
```

**index.js**

```js
const path = require('path');


function createWindow(){
    window = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 960, height: 580,
        resizable: false, maximizable: false,
        frame: false, autoHideMenuBar: true,
        icon: './icon.ico',
        webPreferences: {
            // devTools: false,  // commented for debugging purposes
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('./src/index.html');
    window.webContents.openDevTools(); // Open dev tools to see if any error arised. In this case I saw 'require is not defined' before setting contextIsolation. Remove it when going into production.
}
```