# Electron.remote is undefined even enableRemoteModule is true

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm newbie. I have some problem!

As a title, help me pls.
I got this bug Even if I set enableremotemodule = true.
This is my code

javascript:

```
const $ = require('jquery');
const remote_v = require("electron").remote;
var win = remote.getCurrentWindow();

$('#minimize').click(function(){
  remote_v.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().minimize();
});

$('#close').click(function(){
  remote_v.getCurrentWindow().close();
});
```

main.js

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
function createWindow () {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 530,
    height: 330,
    resizable: false,
    frame : false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
  app.on('activate', function () {

    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})
```

Thank you very much, have a nice day!.

Comment: Hi, what is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Electron.remote is undefined

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68217009/minimize-and-close-buttons-not-working-in-electron-app) also has a solution regarding minimize and close button. It uses `IPC` instead of `remote`.

Comment: i doesn't work :'(

Comment: Where is the first block of javascript code? in `preload.js`?

Answer (score 2):

```
// Deprecated in Electron 12:
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron').remote
```

Install the `@electron/remote` module

```
// Replace with:
const { BrowserWindow } = require('@electron/remote')

// In the main process:
require('@electron/remote/main').initialize()
```

Note: In electron >= 14.0.0, you must use the new enable API to enable the remote module for each desired WebContents separately:

```
require("@electron/remote/main").enable(win.webContents);
```

[Here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/breaking-changes#planned-breaking-api-changes-140) are the changes in the API.
I am sure this helps you figure out the new changes since the remote module is removed from latest electron.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30001373)

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/remote) it's just a syntax problem.

```js
const $ = require('jquery');
const {BrowserWindow} = require("electron").remote;

$('#minimize').click(function(){
  BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().minimize();
});

$('#close').click(function(){
  BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().close();
});
```

Comment: it doesn't work bro :( 
***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'BrowserWindow' of 'require(...).remote' as it is undefined.***

Answer (score 0):

New version of electron ( I use 15.0.0) doesn't have remote module any more. If you look at [documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions), you'll see that it doesn't have enableRemoteModule option. Maybe [this](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main#sending-messages) can help you.

```
 // In main process.
const { ipcMain } = require('electron')
ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg) // prints "ping"
  event.reply('asynchronous-reply', 'pong')
})

ipcMain.on('synchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg) // prints "ping"
  event.returnValue = 'pong'
})

// In renderer process (web page).
// NB. Electron APIs are only accessible from preload, unless contextIsolation is disabled.
// See https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/process-model#preload-scripts for more details.
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
console.log(ipcRenderer.sendSync('synchronous-message', 'ping')) // prints "pong"

ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg) // prints "pong"
})
ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', 'ping')
```